# Butterfly Hunting in Montreux Switzerland

Tags: legal, switzerland, pilgrimages

Later this summer, scores of [literary mavens](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00pcnng) from all over the world will converge on Montreux Switzerland to celebrate [Vladimir Nabokov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Nabokov)'s life and works.  The anniversary of his death is 2nd July.

Only a few will be able to afford the thousands of dollars to stay in the [hotel room where Nabokov spent the final years of his life](http://nabokovsecrethistory.com/news/the-montreux-palace-hotel-nabokovs-final-home/#.VXWVXM9VhBc).  And a very similar few (if any) will be able to access [the museum where his butterfly collection is curated](http://www.lausanne.ch/en/thematiques/culture-et-patrimoine/culture-a-vivre/musees/adresses-musees/musee-cantonal-de-zoologie.html).

Others may wish to recreate [Nabokov's daily hike](https://www.google.com/search?q=nabokov%20butterfly&espv=2&biw=1291&bih=849&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Z5l1VdvbF8GfsgG0rIHYDQ&ved=0CBwQsAQ) through the meadows surrounding Montreux collecting butterflies.  Is this now a regulated activity?  If so, where can one obtain the necessary license?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lepido.ch](http://www.lepido.ch) is a French-language site dedicated to everything related to butterflies in Switzerland with a wealth of practical information.

According to the site, [some butterflies are protected in the whole country](http://www.lepido.ch/materiel-de-terrain) and some cantons add further restrictions on top of that. Bad news for would-be Nabokov followers is that Vaud (where Montreux is located) apparently bans all capture:

> certains cantons interdisent la capture de certaines espèces. S'ajoutent ainsi au point 1 les interdictions de capture suivantes: Schaffhouse: Papilio machaon, Iphiclides podalirius, Nymphalis Antiopa, Inachis io et Vanessa atalanta; Thurgovie: Apatura ilia, Apatura iris, Nymphalis antiopa, Nymphalis polychloros et Lasiommata megera; **Vaud: toutes les espèces (selon RLFaune 922.03.1, Art. 2).**

There is no mention of any license (where capture is authorised) or any way to go around the ban (where it is not) and a quick web search did not turn up anything useful.

The “Règlement d'exécution de la loi du 28 février 1989 sur la faune” does mention a number of species that can be hunted with a license (typical game: hare, deer, etc.) or killed or collected (snails and a few mammals considered harmful) and the possibility to grant an authorisation for “scientific work” by “qualified persons” but nothing else and no mention of butterflies.